# Slide left not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to get the parent div to slide to the left when one of its children is clicked. However, I am receiving the follow error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Property '#' of object # is not a
>   function

```
$(".Area").live("click", function () {
    $(".sliderAreas").hide('slide',{ direction: 'left' }, 1000);
})

<div class="clear sliderAreas">
    <h1>Area</h1>
    <h2>Please Select your Current Location</h2>  
    <br />
    <div class='SkiAreas' id="Report">
       <div class='Area'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I remove the animation options, the default slide action occurs nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the functionality you are trying to use (namely the parameters used in your `hide()` method) is not available in vanilla jQuery - you need to remember to include the [`jQuery UI`](http://jqueryui.com/) library in your project.

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/zGN3f/1/)

Comment: spot on with your answer